# Bookshelf trade not decreasing lower than 3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a librarian villager and cured him once. His bookshelf trade dropped from 9 emeralds to 3. I cured him again, and it stayed at 3. Is it hardcoded to never go below 3 (perhaps becuase that would mean emerald duplication)?

Comment: I think so, because you can break it into books and trade those 1:1 ideally. I heard it once, but I don't have a source right now.

Comment: Maybe this is a recent change or you somehow did something wrong? try testing in creative, last I tried it worked fine

Comment: It was definitely broken ([see here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/doa8ns/if_you_have_a_librarian_and_get_both_the/)), so maybe it was fixed and hardcoded as you think. There's a [ticket on Minecraft bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-153334) about this exploit, and it's labeled as fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not hardcoded. It can decrease upto 2 emeralds (maybe upto 1 emerald, if you are lucky enough).

You can try these methods:

1. Try getting "Hero Of The Village" effect.
2. Try re-curing him.
3. You can keep breaking and replacing the lectern until the amount drops.
4. Just leave him and find another villager.

Comment: How would breaking and replacing the lectern help?

Comment: It resets the trades.

Comment: If I already have a villager upgraded (aka the ones people would be curing for better prices), breaking the lectern would not help